# Laravel has count still returns entries regardless of 0 count

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I'm trying to only bring back `pingtree_group_entries` that have at least one or more `pingtree_entries`.

My query right now is still bringing back models that don't have any.

What am I missing? This is a Laravel 10 project on PHP 8.1

```php
/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show(Company $company, Application $application)
{
    $app = Application::has('pingtree_group.pingtree_group_entries.pingtree.pingtree_entries', '>', 0)->with([
        'modelable',
        'pingtree_group.pingtree_group_entries.pingtree.pingtree_entries'
    ])->where('id', 30)
        ->first();

    return new ApiSuccessResponse($app);
}
```

Currently gives me...

```json
{
    "model": {
        "id": 30,
        "user_id": 1,
        "company_id": 1,
        "country_id": 1,
        "product_id": 1,
        "serve_method_id": 3,
        "application_form_id": 1,
        "pingtree_group_id": 1,
        "affiliate_id": 2,
        "thread_uuid": "93d475da-6668-4633-9c47-ba4ddce3f1c8",
        "status": "declined",
        "modelable_type": "App\\Models\\ApplicationGBPayday",
        "modelable_id": 30,
        "affiliate": "aff4000",
        "brand": null,
        "campaign": null,
        "ip": "172.20.0.1",
        "user_agent": "test",
        "fingerprint": "c5b470a385c80d3d362cd373d55153564615da1e",
        "submitted_at": "2023-03-02T14:18:10.000000Z",
        "created_at": "2023-03-02T14:18:08.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2023-03-02T14:18:10.000000Z",
        "deleted_at": null,
        "display_class": "bg-danger",
        "modelable": {
            "id": 30,
            "user_id": 1,
            "company_id": 1,
            "country_id": 1,
            "product_id": 1,
            "serve_method_id": 3,
            "application_form_id": 1,
            "pingtree_group_id": 1,
            "affiliate_id": 2,
            "ReqLoanAmount": 500,
            "ReqRepaymentTerm": 4,
            "AppLoanPurpose": 0,
            "AppLoanPurposeOther": "Some other reason",
            "AppTitle": 1,
            "AppFirstName": "Ryan",
            "AppLastName": "Doe",
            "AppEmail": "john.doe@gmail.com",
            "AppDOBDay": 20,
            "AppDOBMonth": 1,
            "AppDOBYear": 1950,
            "AppHomePhone": "07111222333",
            "AppWorkPhone": "07111222333",
            "AppMobilePhone": "07111222333",
            "AppMaritalStatus": 0,
            "AppDependants": 0,
            "AppNationality": 0,
            "AppHouseNumber": "4",
            "AppStreet": "Test street",
            "AppTown": "Test town",
            "AppCounty": "Text county",
            "AppPostCode": "CF311JD",
            "AppHomeStatus": 4,
            "AppAddressYears": 2,
            "AppAddressMonths": 10,
            "AppPreviousHouseNumber": null,
            "AppPreviousStreet": null,
            "AppPreviousTown": null,
            "AppPreviousCounty": null,
            "AppPreviousPostCode": null,
            "AppPreviousHomeStatus": 0,
            "AppPreviousAddressYears": 5,
            "AppPreviousAddressMonths": 2,
            "EmpIncomeType": 0,
            "EmpEmployerName": "ASDA",
            "EmpIndustry": 22,
            "EmpNetMonthlyPay": 2500,
            "EmpPayFrequency": 10,
            "EmpDirectPayment": 0,
            "EmpNextPayDay": 20,
            "EmpNextPayMonth": 12,
            "EmpNextPayYear": 2023,
            "EmpFollowingPayDay": 20,
            "EmpFollowingPayMonth": 4,
            "EmpFollowingPayYear": 2023,
            "EmpJobTitle": "Worker",
            "EmpEmployedYears": 10,
            "EmpEmployedMonths": 20,
            "NextPaydate": "2023-04-20T00:00:00.000000Z",
            "FollowingPaydate": "2023-04-20T00:00:00.000000Z",
            "BankName": "Monzo",
            "BankAccount": "12345678",
            "BankSortcode": "123456",
            "BankTime": 90,
            "BankDebitCard": 1,
            "EmpAddress": null,
            "EmpAddress2": "Emp street",
            "EmpTown": null,
            "EmpCounty": null,
            "EmpPostCode": null,
            "EmpPreviousIncomeType": 0,
            "EmpPreviousEmployerName": "John doe",
            "EmpPreviousIndustry": 25,
            "EmpPreviousJobTitle": "Worker",
            "EmpPreviousEmployedYears": 0,
            "EmpPreviousEmployedMonths": 0,
            "EmpPreviousAddress": "4",
            "EmpPreviousAddress2": "Emp previous street",
            "EmpPreviousTown": "Emp previous town",
            "EmpPreviousCounty": "Emp previous postcode",
            "EmpPreviousPostCode": null,
            "AppHouseholdIncome": 2500,
            "AppHousingSpend": 500,
            "AppUtilitiesSpend": 100,
            "AppFoodSpend": 100,
            "AppTransportSpend": 0,
            "AppCreditSpend": 100,
            "AppOtherSpend": 0,
            "ReqTermsOptIn": true,
            "ReqMarketingOptIn": false,
            "created_at": "2023-03-02T14:18:08.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2023-03-02T14:18:08.000000Z",
            "deleted_at": null
        },
        "pingtree_group": {
            "id": 1,
            "user_id": 1,
            "company_id": 1,
            "name": "Aff4000TG",
            "description": "Tree ported from https://rdrt.org/system/edit_tree/130",
            "is_default": false,
            "is_enabled": true,
            "created_at": "2023-03-02T08:59:08.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2023-03-03T11:57:29.000000Z",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "is_deleting": false,
            "pingtree_group_entries": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "user_id": 1,
                    "company_id": 1,
                    "pingtree_group_id": 1,
                    "pingtree_id": 1,
                    "pick_chance": 5,
                    "is_enabled": true,
                    "created_at": "2023-03-02T08:59:08.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2023-03-03T16:48:11.000000Z",
                    "pick_chance_formatted": "5%",
                    "pingtree": {
                        "id": 1,
                        "user_id": 1,
                        "company_id": 1,
                        "name": "Aff4000-T1",
                        "description": "Tree ported from https://rdrt.org/system/edit_tree/130 to work with Aff4000TG.",
                        "is_enabled": true,
                        "created_at": "2023-03-02T08:59:08.000000Z",
                        "updated_at": "2023-03-02T08:59:08.000000Z",
                        "deleted_at": null,
                        "is_deleting": false,
                        "pingtree_entries": [
                            {
                                "id": 1,
                                "user_id": 1,
                                "company_id": 1,
                                "buyer_tier_id": 1,
                                "pingtree_id": 1,
                                "processing_order": 0,
                                "created_at": "2023-03-02T08:59:08.000000Z",
                                "updated_at": "2023-03-02T08:59:08.000000Z"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "user_id": 1,
                    "company_id": 1,
                    "pingtree_group_id": 1,
                    "pingtree_id": 2,
                    "pick_chance": 90,
                    "is_enabled": true,
                    "created_at": "2023-03-02T15:17:56.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2023-03-03T16:48:11.000000Z",
                    "pick_chance_formatted": "90%",
                    "pingtree": {
                        "id": 2,
                        "user_id": 1,
                        "company_id": 1,
                        "name": "Main campaign tree",
                        "description": "The main campaign tree, designed for primary use.",
                        "is_enabled": true,
                        "created_at": "2023-03-02T08:59:08.000000Z",
                        "updated_at": "2023-03-02T08:59:08.000000Z",
                        "deleted_at": null,
                        "is_deleting": false,
                        "pingtree_entries": []
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

You see that the second pingtree group entry's pingtree entries are empty but the model is still here? I need to completely exclude the whole item from `pingtree_group_entries`.

Comment: Try with `Application::whereHas`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function show(Company $company, Application $application)
{
    $app = Application::with([
        'modelable',
        'pingtree_group.pingtree_group_entries.pingtree' => function($query){
            $query->withCount('pingtree_entries AS pingtree_entries_count');
        }
      ])->where('id', 30)
        ->having('pingtree_entries_count', '>', 0)
        ->first();

    return new ApiSuccessResponse($app);
}
```

Comment: This gives me the following error: `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'pingtree_entries_count' in 'having clause' (Connection: mysql, SQL: select * from `applications` where `id` = 30 and `applications`.`deleted_at` is null having `pingtree_entries_count` > 0 limit 1)",
    "exception": "Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException`

Comment: @RyanH updated the answer try again please.

Comment: @RyanH did the new answer work?